# i have a textbox which extract the content of dropdownlist now whenever i change the extracted content it should be saved into database

Tags: php

I have a text box which extracts the content of dropdownlist.Now whenever i extract the content i too need to edit it ana save it into the database.How can i do????
Here is my code:

```
  <?php 

    require'conn.php';
    $select_query="Select dynamictext from tbl_content where type=1";
    $select_query_run =mysql_query($select_query);
    echo'Dynamictext:';
    echo "<select name='dynamic text' id='names' >";
    while ($select_query_array= mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
    {
        $value=$select_query_array["dynamictext"];
       echo "<option value='$value' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["dynamictext"])."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to use [`UPDATE`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Comment: how to do the coding part????

Comment: Your question is super unclear to me. Which of these are you trying to do: (Option A) Get data out of your database to build your HTML drop-down list dynamically for the user to pick from, or (Option B) Push the drop-down value selected by the user into the database? Your question sounds like Option B, but your code looks like Option A.

Comment: @filmnut OP wants to do both Option A and B.So as far now he got code for Option A and asking code for Option B

Comment: I just need to save the content of a textbox thats it

Comment: I just need to save the content of a textbox into datbase how can i do it can u help me with the coding part?plzzzz

Answer (score 0):

*Based on the clarification I got above from @krisha above, I'm going to take a stab at answering this. You'll want to refer to my comment above, for a definition of (Option A) and (Option B), as I defined them.*

Let's assume you've got (Option A) working and that (as far as the `select` HTML element is concerned), it is functional.

Let's also assume that you know to do the following:

- Place the `select` tag inside of a `form` tag.
- Set the `form` tag's `action` and `method` values.
- Place a `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` inside of the `form` tag.

If none of the above made sense, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).

Once you've done everything above, that will result in the value of the HTML drop-down being available to PHP after the user clicks the **Submit** button and the page refreshes. How the value of the drop-down is passed through the submit process will depend on the `method` value you pass to the `form` tag. I'll assume you use `method="get"` (which will result in the value of the drop-down appearing in the URL after the refresh). If you want more info on `get` versus `post`, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Once the refresh occurs, you use PHP's [`$_GET[""]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to retrieve the value of the HTML drop-down. In your case, you would use `$_GET["dynamic text"]` (since the `name` of your select is `dynamic text`). You could set this value to a variable, like so:

```
$value_of_select = $_GET["dynamic text"];
```

At this point, you have the value the user selected from the HTML drop-down. Now, push it to the database. It looks like you already understand how to pass queries to a database. The only difference in this case is that you want to do an [`insert`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) or an [`update`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp), not a `select`.